# Sending Emails from Google Spreadsheet "ONLY ONCE"

Tags: google-sheets, email

I have imported live data to Google Spreadsheets using IMPORTHTML function. My requirement is that I need to send an email each time the value of the cell goes beyond a particular number. I found the following on web,

```
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Profit Ratio");

   var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("D7").getValue();

   if(valueToCheck > 3) {
       MailApp.sendEmail("zak*******@gmail.com", "Current Profit Ratio", "Current Profit Ratio is 1:" + valueToCheck+ " !!!");
   }
}
```

But the problem with this is that if the value goes beyond **3**, it keeps sending emails every minute till it goes below 3. I don't want that to happen. I want an email send only once if it goes above 3, and next email must be when it again goes beyond 3 after having gone down. Also, I wish to get make  `3<it<10`. How do I do both these?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties service to keep track of whether the current satisfaction of criteria has already been dealt with between executions.

```
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Profit Ratio");
  var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("D7").getValue();
  var prop = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties(); // Quick access to properties


  if (valueToCheck > 3                         // Between 3 and 10
        && valueToCheck < 10 
        && !prop.getProperty("processed") {    // Has not been dealt with
    MailApp.sendEmail(
        "zak*******@gmail.com", 
        "Current Profit Ratio", 
        "Current Profit Ratio is 1:" + valueToCheck + " !!!");
    prop.setProperty("processed", true);       // Switch the flag so we don't send any more emails
  } else if (valueToCheck <= 3) {              // You might want to add || value to check >= 10 here?
    prop.setProperty("processed", false);      // Set property to false so that next time the value exceeds 3 we process it again
  }
}
```